# Prove normalizing constant on normal CDF

Tags: probability, integration

So I know that the CDF of a standard normal will be:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{
\frac{-z^2}{2}} \, dz   $$

How do I show that when I sub in mu and sigma, the equation will become:

$$ \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} \,dy  $$

The terms inside the integral are easy, but how do I know the sigma outside the integral correctly fixes the normalization?

Comment: I filled in the missing minus signs.  The TeX style was hideous, with lots of things like {{{2}{\pi}}} where 2\pi would suffice.  I changed that because I don't think we should encourage people to do that.  They sometimes get ideas from looking at how others have coded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the substitution $t=\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma}$. Then $\frac{dy}{\sigma}=dt$.  Then from the fact that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-t^2/2}=1$, it follows that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(y-\mu)/2\sigma^2} \,dy=1$.

Comment: Yep, that makes sense. Thanks.